# Proof Verification: Effectiveness of Tarski-Vaught Test

Tags: logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic

Here is the definition of the Tarski-Vaught test from Marker's *Model Theory: An Introduction* page 44.

> **Proposition 2.3.5 (Tarski-Vaught Test)** Suppose that $M$ is a substructure of $N$, then $M$ is an elementary substructure of $N$ if and only if, for any formula $\varphi(v, \bar{w})$ and $\bar{a} \in M$, if there is a $b \in N$ such that $N \models \varphi(b, \bar{a})$, then there is a $c \in M$ such that $M \models \varphi(c, \bar{a})$.

I took a look at the proof in Marker and used its idea to structurally induct on a well-formed formula, but didn't otherwise use the proof there since I don't really understand it. Some things about this proof are deliberately different from Marker's proof. For example, I'm not considering arbitrary formulas headed by $\lnot$.

I attempted to prove this theorem myself to get a better understanding of it.

---

Here is my attempt to prove it.

I assume the *traditional semantics* for first-order logic; empty models are forbidden.

I assume that all formulas are in prenex-normal form with the matrix in negative normal form. I will call this **game form** because it is reminiscent of the game semantics for first-order logic.

Let the Tarski-Vaught property be defined as follows.

Let $p$ be a mapping from variable symbols to values in $A$; $p$ is a *parameter map*. $p$ is not a general parameter map though, it always maps variable symbols to elements of $A$.

Suppose $A$ is a substructure of $B$.

$$ \frac{B \models \varphi(x, p) \;\; \text{for some $x$ in $B$} }{B \models \varphi(x, p) \;\; \text{for some $x$ in $A$} } \;\; \text{for all $\varphi(x, p)$} \;\;\textit{is the Tarski-Vaught property} $$

##### Remark 102: characterizations of elementary substructurehood.

$A$ is an elementary substructure of $B$ if and only if, for all sentences $\varphi(p)$, $A \models \varphi(p)$ if and only if $B \models \varphi(p)$.

Equivalently, $A$ is an elementary substructure of $B$ if and only if $B \models \text{ElDiag}(A)$.

$A$ is an elementary substructure of $B$ if and only if the following two properties hold:

- $A \models \varphi(p)$ implies $B \models \varphi(p)$ for all $\varphi(p)$.
- $B \models \varphi(p)$ implies $A \models \varphi(p)$ for all $\varphi(p)$.

##### Definition 105: The definition of the dual

If $\varphi(p)$ is a sentence in game form, let $\text{dual}(\varphi, p)$ be the unique formula obtained by replacing $\forall$ with $\exists$, $\exists$ with $\forall$, $\land$ with $\lor$, $\lor$ with $\land$, and by replacing $\lnot R(\cdots)$ with $R(\cdots)$ and $R(\cdots)$ with $\lnot R(\cdots)$.

$ M \models \varphi(p) $ holds if and only if $ M \models \text{dual}(\varphi, p)$ fails.

##### Lemma 101: If $A$ is an elementary substructure of $B$, then the Tarski-Vaught property holds.

This follows immediately from remark 102.

##### Lemma 103: The Tarski-Vaught property implies that ($B \models \varphi(p)$ implies $A \models \varphi(p)$ for all $\varphi(p)$).

Suppose $\varphi(p)$ is quantifier-free.

If $\varphi(p)$ is a negative literal, then it has the form $\lnot R(t_1, \cdots, t_n)$.

By the definition of a substructure, $\lnot R( \cdots )$ would hold in $A$ as well.

If $\varphi(p)$ is a positive literal, then it has the form $R(\cdots)$.

For a given $R(t_1, t_2, \cdots)$, consider the formulas $\square = t_1 \land R(t_1, t_2, \cdots)$, $\square = t_2 \land R(\cdots)$, and so on, where $\square$ is a hole to be filled by a parameter. Since those formulas are satisfiable-via-parameters in $B$, they are also satisfiable by parameters in $A$.

Let $\varphi(p)$ be a formula of the form $\alpha(p) \land \beta(p)$ and suppose Lemma 103 holds for all formulas with fewer connectives than $\varphi(p)$.

$$ B \models \alpha(p) \land \beta(p) \;\; \textit{by hypothesis} $$
$$ B \models \alpha(p) \;\;\text{and}\;\; B \models \beta(p) $$
$$ \textit{by our inductive hypothesis}\;\; A \models \alpha(p) \;\;\text{and}\;\; A \models \beta(p)$$
$$ \textit{Thus} \;\; A \models \alpha(p) \land \beta(p) $$

Let $\varphi(p)$ be a formula of the form $\alpha(p) \lor \beta(p)$ and support Lemma 103 holds for all formulas with fewer connectives than $\varphi(p)$.

$$ B \models \alpha(p) \lor \beta(p) \;\; \textit{by hypothesis} $$
$$ B \models \alpha(p) \;\;\text{or}\;\; B \models \beta(p) $$
$$ \textit{by our inductive hypothesis}\;\; A \models \alpha(p) \;\;\text{or}\;\; A \models \beta(p)$$
$$ \textit{Thus} \;\; A \models \alpha(p) \lor \beta(p) $$

Thus, $B \models \varphi(p)$ implies $A \models \varphi(p)$ in cases where $\varphi$ is quantifier-free.

Suppose $\varphi(p)$ contains exactly one quantifier and it is $\exists$.

Thus $\varphi$ is of the form $\exists x \mathop. \alpha(x, p)$ where $\alpha$ is quantifier-free (q.f.).

$$ B \models \exists x \mathop. \alpha(x, p) \;\;\textit{by hypothesis} $$
$$ \textit{Thus} \;\; B \models \alpha(d, p) \;\; \textit{for some $d$ in $B$} $$
$$ \textit{Thus} \;\; B \models \alpha(e, p) \;\; \textit{for some $e$ in $A$} $$
$$ \textit{Since $\alpha$ is q.f.} \;\; A \models \alpha(e, p) \;\; \textit{for some $e$ in $A$} $$
$$ \textit{Thus, as desired} \;\; A \models \exists x \mathop. \alpha(x, p) $$

Suppose $\varphi(p)$ has multiple quantifiers and (103) holds for all well-formed formulas with strictly fewer quantifiers than $\varphi(p)$.

$$ B \models \exists x \mathop. \alpha(x, p) \;\;\textit{by hypothesis} $$
$$ \textit{Thus} \;\; B \models \alpha(d, p) \;\; \textit{for some $d$ in $B$} $$
$$ \textit{Thus} \;\; B \models \alpha(e, p) \;\; \textit{for some $e$ in $A$} $$
$$ \textit{By our inductive hypothesis} \;\; A \models \alpha(e, p) \;\; \textit{for some $e$ in $A$} $$
$$ \textit{Thus, as desired} \;\; A \models \exists x \mathop. \alpha(x, p) $$

Suppose $\varphi(p)$ has exactly one quantifier and it is $\forall$.

$$ B \models \forall x \mathop. \alpha(x, p) \;\; \textit{by hypothesis} $$
$$ \textit{Thus}\;\; B \models \forall x \mathop. \alpha(x, p) $$
$$ \textit{Thus}\;\; B \models \alpha(d, p) \;\; \textit{for all $d$ in $B$}$$
$$ \textit{Thus}\;\; B \models \alpha(d, p) \;\; \textit{for all $d$ in $A$}$$
$$ \textit{Since $\alpha$ is q.f.}\;\; A \models \alpha(d, p) \;\; \textit{for all $d$ in $A$} $$
$$ \textit{Thus, as desired} \;\; A \models \forall x \mathop. \alpha(x, p) $$

Suppose $\varphi(p)$ has multiple quantifiers and is headed by $\forall$, and lemma 103 holds for all well-formed formulas with strictly fewer quantifiers than $\varphi(p)$.

$$ B \models \forall x \mathop. \alpha(x, p) \;\; \textit{by hypothesis} $$
$$ \textit{Thus}\;\; B \models \forall x \mathop. \alpha(x, p) $$
$$ \textit{Thus}\;\; B \models \alpha(d, p) \;\; \textit{for all $d$ in $B$}$$
$$ \textit{Thus}\;\; B \models \alpha(d, p) \;\; \textit{for all $d$ in $A$}$$
$$ \textit{By our inductive hypothesis}\;\; A \models \alpha(d, p) \;\; \textit{for all $d$ in $A$} $$
$$ \textit{Thus, as desired} \;\; A \models \forall x \mathop. \alpha(x, p) $$

Thus Lemma 103 holds.

##### Lemma 104: The Tarski-Vaught property implies that ($A \models \varphi(p)$ implies $B \models \varphi(p)$ for all $\varphi(p)$).

Suppose the Tarski-Vaught property holds for all $\psi(p)$.

Then, by Lemma 103, we know that $B \models \psi(p)$ implies $A \models \psi(p)$ for all $\psi(p)$).

Choose $\psi(p)$ to be equal to $\text{dual}(\varphi, p)$.

$B \models \text{dual}(\varphi, p)$ implies $A \models \text{dual}(\varphi, p)$.

Thus, $B \nvDash \varphi(p)$ implies $A \nvDash \varphi(p)$.

Thus, $A \models \varphi(p)$ implies $B \models \varphi(p)$.

This proves Lemma 104.

##### Lemma 105: The Tarski-Vaught test succeeds if and only if $A$ is an elementary substructure of $B$.

This holds by Lemma 101, 103, and 104.

Comment: hi Greg. I haven't read through your proof attempt, but if you don't mind me asking what's unclear to you about Marker's proof? the approach he gives is very natural, and quite "clean" in the sense that you don't really have to worry about the syntax of the formula at all. (eg there's no need to write things in prenex normal form or distinguish the case where there's one quantifier versus multiple, or distinguish between $\forall$ and $\exists$ quantifiers – note that if you handle $\exists$ and negation then you automatically handle $\forall$)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom In order to complete the proof in Marker, I think we need to talk about passing from a structure $M$ to one with builtin Skolem functions. That seemed sort of intricate and got me wondering whether there were alternative approaches to proving the theorem. I thought it would be a good idea to spend some time trying to prove the theorem without using this mechanism before going back and trying to see what work it's doing. (edit: I also didn't follow the argument in the book for why removing negation is justified)

Comment: what makes you think we need builtin Skolem functions? there's no need for them! for the negation step you just argue as follows. suppose $\varphi(\bar{x})$ is of form $\neg\psi(\bar{x})$, where by the induction hypothesis we know $M\models\psi(\bar{a})$ if and only if $N\models\psi(\bar{a})$ for every tuple $\bar{a}$ of elements of $M$. we wish to show that $M\models\varphi(\bar{a})$ if and only if $N\models\varphi(\bar{a})$ for every tuple $\bar{a}$ of elements of $M$; do you see why this follows from knowing the corresponding fact about $\psi$?

Comment: (also, regarding your edit: it's not the case that Marker's proof inducts on formulas headed by $\neg$. instead it inducts on *arbitrary* formulas that are built up from atomic formulas and the logical symbols $\neg$,$\exists$, and $\wedge$; this is what I mean when I say his proof doesn't really need to worry about syntax at all.)

Comment: Oh. I see. It appears that the proof is completed within the paragraph on page 44 instead of spilling over into the next section. :/ I misread that. Also, Marker's inductive hypothesis is a biconditional ... which explains how the $\exists$ works. Thanks for the clarification; that really helps!

Comment: oh yes, I see why you were confused now; I had forgotten Marker's book has the slightly frustrating typographical convention of not including "end of proof" symbols! anyway, my pleasure; happy it helped :)

Comment: In your statement of the Task-Vaught test, the $M\models\varphi(b,\bar a)$ should presumably be $N\models\varphi(c,\bar a)$